# Polars - Update value of column based on the previous value

Tags: python-polars

I want to modify a string column to float column. It consists of volume with "k" and "mm", which represents thousand and million, respectively. My focus is to change them all to million and float

```
test = pl.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
                     "col2": ["500K", "1MM", "25K", "2.5MM", "2MM", "600K", "800K", "1.5MM", "5MM", "350k"]})

test.with_columns(
    pl.when(
    pl.col("col2").str.contains("MM$"))
    .then(pl.col("col2")
         .str.replace("MM$", "")
         .str.strip())
    .otherwise(pl.col("col2")
               .str.replace("K$", "")
               .str.strip()
               .cast(pl.Float32)/1000)
)
```

The last line ".cast(pl.Float32)/1000" doens't work. I do know of another solution, but I'd have to read the dataframe column twice. I'm aiming on a solution that reads only once. Thank you

Here is the solution for my test case:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd need to do all the replace/casting in one place e.g.

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("col2")
     .str.replace("(?:MM|[kK])$", "")
     .cast(pl.Float32)
   /
   pl.when(pl.col("col2").str.contains("[kK]$"))
     .then(1000)
     .otherwise(1)
)
```

```
shape: (10, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ col1 | col2  │
│ ---  | ---   │
│ str  | f64   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ a    | 0.5   │
│ b    | 1.0   │
│ c    | 0.025 │
│ d    | 2.5   │
│ ...  | ...   │
│ g    | 0.8   │
│ h    | 1.5   │
│ i    | 5.0   │
│ j    | 0.35  │
└──────┴───────┘
```

This is what is happening with each step in its own `.with_columns`:

```
(df
 .with_columns(
    num = pl.col("col2").str.replace("(?:MM|[kK])$", ""))
 .with_columns(
    denom = 
       pl.when(pl.col("col2").str.contains("[kK]$"))
         .then(1000)
         .otherwise(1))
 .with_columns(
    result = pl.col("num").cast(pl.Float32) / pl.col("denom"))
)
```

```
shape: (10, 5)
┌──────┬───────┬─────┬───────┬────────┐
│ col1 | col2  | num | denom | result │
│ ---  | ---   | --- | ---   | ---    │
│ str  | str   | str | i32   | f64    │
╞══════╪═══════╪═════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ a    | 500K  | 500 | 1000  | 0.5    │
│ b    | 1MM   | 1   | 1     | 1.0    │
│ c    | 25K   | 25  | 1000  | 0.025  │
│ d    | 2.5MM | 2.5 | 1     | 2.5    │
│ ...  | ...   | ... | ...   | ...    │
│ g    | 800K  | 800 | 1000  | 0.8    │
│ h    | 1.5MM | 1.5 | 1     | 1.5    │
│ i    | 5MM   | 5   | 1     | 5.0    │
│ j    | 350k  | 350 | 1000  | 0.35   │
└──────┴───────┴─────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Quite interesting. So the pl.when will read the old dataframe, even though the replace is before it?

Comment: It's not specific to `pl.when`, like if you do: `.with_columns(a = pl.col("col1") + 1, b = pl.col("col1") + 2)` they're 2 separate expressions that are generated in isolation from each other.

Comment: Since you're creating two new columns, it makes more sense to me than when we're changing the input

Comment: Basically, in your answer, you're still reading it twice, but with the optmization of them being inside the same with_columns. What I was doing was something similar with your edit in your post. 
From your perspective, what is preferred from community, modify the input column or create a new one? A few more memory usage vs more readability, I guess?

Comment: A new column is always created. The first example isn't modifying the input column, if you explicitly name the result, you will see a new column created. Because it has the name `col2` - it replaces the previous `col2` column. You also don't have to worry about "reading the column twice" - polars takes care of that: "All expressions are run in parallel"

Comment: As long it is inside the same with_columns, I think.
Thank you, man!